# Convert pdf in landscape mode using pdfcrowd API

Tags: codeigniter, html-to-pdf

I have been using pdfCrowd API to convert HTML to PDF, but the default page orientation set for conversion is portrait. So, is there any way to set the page orientation to landscape.

Comment: check this link: http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code try it

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Landscape-mode: 3pdf,'L'");
```